# esconder variavel na url com htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, variáveis, url

Gostaria de saber se existe algum jeito de esconder um subdiretório ou uma variável na url amigável? Exemplo:

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/categoria-([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)$ index.php?link=6&categoriaid=$1
```

neste caso , eu passo o id da categoria via url que ficaria assim :

```
www.com.br/19/categoria-teste
```

neste caso trabalha ok, mas o que eu realmente quero é que oculte o ide da categoria para o usuário e mostra assim

```
www.com.br/categoria-teste
```

mas é claro, passando o `id` da variável ocultamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro recomendo que aprenda [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), a sua está errada (e esta funcionando por "sorte"):

```
[a-z,0-9,A-Z,-]
```

Dentro de `[...]` não se usa virgula para separar, todos valores são detectados, o correto seria algo como:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/categoria-([a-z0-9A-Z_\-]+)$ index.php?link=6&categoriaid=$1
```

Como o ID deve ser numérico troquei por `\d`

Não tem como ocultar o id que esta entre `/<id>/categoria-<nome>`, veja as proprias URLs do stackoverflow ficam assim:

```
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164248/esconder-variavel-na-url-com-htaccess
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/<id>/<nome>
```

Talvez você possa usar assim:

```
http://site/categoria-teste-19
http://site/categoria-<nome>-<id>
```

O Regex ficaria assim:

```
RewriteRule ^/categoria-([a-z0-9A-Z_\-]+)\-(\d+)$ index.php?link=6&categoriaid=$2
```

Comment: um outro metodo que andei pesquisando seria passar o id via session enquando a url ficaria sem id , assim quando clicasse no botao , criaria asession com o id e na outra pagina receberia a session e deletaria ela , assim a url fica limpa , mas nao encontrei um modo de criar a session com ao clicar em um link

Comment: @JonnysJ. a ideia é até boa, mas não funcionaria para indexar no google.

Comment: a legal guilherme, obrigado por me informar, entao nao vou perder tempo tentando criar isto , vou deixar padrao mesmo

Answer (score 3):

Jonnys, se você não passa a informação na URL não tem como obtê-la pra fazer o tratamento no arquivo .htaccess, como foi feito no exemplo que você deu.

Se você quer ter uma URL personalizada sem a necessidade de deixar o ID explícito, pense na possibilidade de usar slugs, assim você pesquisa pelo slug e não pelo ID.

O .htaccess ficaria mais ou menos assim para a url www.com.br/categoria-teste:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```