# ocultar id passado na url

Tags: php, sql, laravel

é o seguinte, na aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, tenho um formulário de denúncia onde o usuário não precisa está logado para preenche-lo e fazer sua devida denúncia, até ai tudo certo, assim que ele envia os dados é exibido para ele uma (página)view com as informações que ele preencheu. No entanto, assim que essa pagina(view) é exibida com as informações, o id do cadastro é exibido na url, e dessa forma estou dendo um problema de segurança.

por exemplo:
se usuário fez um cadastro é exibido para ele a view com as informações que ele cadastrou e a seguinte url
http://127.0.0.1:8000/controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia?dados=40

mas caso o usuário passe outro id manualmente na url é exibido para ele os dados dessa outra denúncia
http://127.0.0.1:8000/controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia?dados=41

obs: estou usando o framework laravel

tem alguma maneira de evitar essa situação?

Este é o controller responsável por chamar e valiar o formulário de denuncia

```html
   public function adiciona(){
    return view('AdminDenunciaView.adicionaDenuncia');
}
 public function adicionaAction(Request $request){ 
    $request->validate([
      'crime'=>['required','string'],
      'descricao'=>['required','string','min:10','max:200'],
    ]);
    $crime = $request->input('crime');
    $descricao = $request->input('descricao');
        
    $data = new Denuncia();
    $data-> crime = $crime;
    $data-> descricao = $descricao;
    $data-> save();
   return redirect()->route('exibeInformacaoDenuncia',['data'=>$data]);
}
```

Este é controller responsável por chamar a view com as informações cadastradas

```html
public function exibe(Request $id){
   $data = Denuncia::find($id);
   return view('AdminDenunciaView.exibeInformacaoDenuncia',['data'=>$data]);  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Não tem como esconder o ID em GET: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164252/3635 ... outra coisa não tem sentido querer esconder o IDENTIFICADOR, ele serve para isso, identificar, se sua intenção que as pessoas não presumam o numero de itens (no seu caso denuncias) você pode simplesmente usar no seu migration o UUID (versão 4 com 2<sup>122</sup>) junto com o método `->primary()`, assim:

```
$table->uuid('id')->primary();
```

O problema de UUID é que existe uma ínfima possibilidade de colisão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40528/3635

O problema do UUID é que cada banco tem um esquema para ajustar isso, exemplos:

- Postgres terá que setar a coluna ID com valor default: `uuid_generate_v4()` (que vai precisar instalar a extensão PostGIS)
- Postgres 13 creio que terá nativo, que é a função `gen_random_uuid()` (não testei ainda)
- Mysql provavelmente vai ter que usar valor default como `UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())` (supondo que use `BINARY` para o tipo da coluna) e depois `BIN_TO_UUID(id)` no select

Eu não vou entrar em detalhes, só vou dizer que a maioria das pessoas resolve do lado do PHP no Model do Laravel, para fazer poucos INSERTs não será problemático, mas para inserir milhares no lado PHP será bem mais lento, já que terá que processar um a um, então eu não gosto muito disso:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class Exemplo extends \GoldSpecDigital\LaravelEloquentUUID\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    //
}
```

O exemplo foi com o `composer require goldspecdigital/laravel-eloquent-uuid:^7.0`, mas dá pra fazer manualmente, o que é até que simples, mas ainda sim fazer isso no Eloquent se vier precisar processar muitas coisas pode ser demorado (é possivel que assim que tiver um tempo irei formular perguntas sobre como resolver para cada SGDB mais popular, se for possivel ou vantajoso é claro)

---

Seja com UUID ou ID, como "perfumaria" ao invés dequerystring você poderia mudar o esquema de rota, ao invés de:

```
/controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia?dados=41
/controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia?dados=d7266915-f014-485c-a2dc-85a2b81d94cd
```

Usaria:

```
/controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia/41
/controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia/d7266915-f014-485c-a2dc-85a2b81d94cd
```

E na rota deve nomeá-la:

```
Route::get('exibeInformacaoDenuncia/{dados}', [
   'as' => 'rotaDenuncia',
   'uses' => 'NomeDoController@exibe'
]);
```

E se for redirecionar seria algo como:

```
return redirect()->route('rotaDenuncia', [ $id ]);
```

### Mascarando o ID

Ao invés de usar UUID, que exige muita configuração dependendo do SGBD, tem gente que resolve isso no model do *Eloquent*, o que pessoalmente acho que se for inserir muitos dados ao mesmo tempo será péssimo em performance, então uma forma simples para evitar que presumam a quantidade bastaria SOMAR e SUBTRAIR o valor do ID, por exemplo, no `.env` aplicar algo como:

```
MASK_ID=5000
```

Após criar com o Model passe o ID assim:

```
return redirect()->route('rotaDenuncia', [ $dados->id + env('MASK_ID') ]);
```

Dessa forma o ID 41 será **somando** com 5000 e irá exibir na URL como:

```
/controledenuncia/exibeInformacaoDenuncia/5041
```

E na hora de ler usando `find()`, faça a **subtração** assim `$id - env('MASK_ID')` (supondo que seu namespace seja mais ou menos assim):

```
public function exibe(Request $request, $id)
{
   $data = Denuncia::find($id - env('MASK_ID'));
   return view('AdminDenunciaView.exibeInformacaoDenuncia', ['data'=>$data]);  
}
```

Comment: olá guilherme, muito obg pelo feedback, ao tentar colocar em pratica as suas dicas no metodo exibe() recebo o seguinte erro 
Object of class Illuminate\Http\Request could not be converted to number

Comment: @frdmarkes ah entendi, foi erro meu, 1 min

Comment: @frdmarkes corrigi na resposta, o correto é:  `public function exibe(Request $request, $id)`, desculpe o equivoco.

Comment: olá Guilherme, mais ma vez, valeu mesmo por ta tentado me ajudar. Estou recebendo uma outra resposta, olha só: é como se ele esperasse ser passado apenas 1 parametro:                           
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AdminDenunciaController\InformacoesController::exibe(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: @frdmarkes você mudou a rota para `Route::get('exibeInformacaoDenuncia/{dados}', ...` ? Entende como funciona os parametros de rotas?

Comment: Dei +1 pela primeira alternativa, a segunda parece não fazer sentido. Se está sempre adicionando e subtraindo 5000 (neste caso), então ao invés trocar `/41` para `/42` iria trocar de `/5041` para `/5042` e teria o mesmo resultado. Não?

Comment: Obrigado caro @Inkeliz, sobre o MASK_ID, vou tentar elucidar me baseando em uma pergunta... qual é o objetivo geralmente de alguém que usa UUID como IDs? Mesmo que isso em alguns SGDBs tenha uma performance pior que usar INTEIROS.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que existem vários objetivos, mas o principal (neste caso) seria de impedir acessar outros conteúdos. Isso é, se houvesse um `youtube.com/v/123` eu poderia alterar para `/124` e acabar acessando um vídeo privado. Este é um caso similar ao do OP. Porém, a soma e subtração não resolve este problema, ao meu ver. Já que agora você tem `/5041` e eu posso ainda alterar para `/5042`, eles continuam sequenciais e facilmente acessíveis. Mesmo se multiplicar, eles continuariam sequenciais (crie duas denuncias  e já era). Ou, estou com sono e perdi alguma informação. haha

Comment: Caro @Inkeliz se formato numerico fosse falha de segurança a anos teria sido abandonado, porque se for possivel acessar conteudo que não lhe pertence mudando o ID na URL então o problema não é o formato e sim a aplicação ... na verdade o unico problema que trocar para UUID resolve é evitar as pessoas deduzirem a quantidade de itens que existe de um tipo de informação.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o objetivo do OP é justamente ocultar a informação e impedir que outros acessem o conteúdo, não tem qualquer relação com quantidade de item. Ele diz que: "mas caso o usuário passe outro id manualmente na url é exibido para ele os dados dessa outra denúncia". Não estou falando de formato número ou não, mas somar e subtrair como forma de impedir deduzir outros IDs não resolve a questão do OP. O uso de IDs aleatórios impediriam isso (que é o mesmo do fim UUID), ao menos teria mto mais trabalho, principalmente unido à um rate-limit, e outras autenticações (que o OP não tem).

Comment: @Inkeliz e por isso eu disse no começo da pergunta, isso não faz sentido, não é necessário.... a unica utilidade que existe nisso é só será para deduzir valores, para outros objetivos assim é apenas falta de compreensão, ID tem o objetivo de IDentificar algo, você não ganha nada ocultado.

Answer (score 2):

> mas caso o usuário passe outro id manualmente na url é exibido para ele os dados dessa outra denúncia

Acho que para impedir isso teria que utilizar IDs não-sequenciais (como mencionado por @Guilherme Nascimento), desde que se atente a quantidade de denuncias que existem, afinal quanto mais denuncias existirem maior serão as chances de encontrar um ID válido.

---

*Não tenho conhecimento sobre Laravel, então estou usando apenas os recursos nativos do PHP, e que, provavelmente, terão que ser adaptados para o Laravel.*

---

Um outra possibilidade, seria criar um tipo básico de autenticação e que ainda não precise de outras informações do usuário (e muito menos, não precise de login).

Isto poderia ser feito com HMAC (ou Ed25519, se quiser assinaturas de chaves-públicas), afim de simplificar irei usar o HMAC:

```
$id = 40;

// Via LibSodium (Blake2):
$hmac = sodium_crypto_generichash($id, $chave);

// Via PHP (SHA256):
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $id, $chave);
```

Dessa forma, ao invés do usuário acessar por:

```
?dados= $id
```

Ele terá que ter a "assinatura":

```
?dados= $id &assinatura= $hmac
```

---

Portanto, se ele alterar o `id` ele não terá a assinatura válida correspondente, o usuário será incapaz de criar uma `assinatura` válida sem saber o valor da `$chave`. Quando for mostrar o resultado, deverá fazer algo como:

```
if (!is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
   return
}

if(!hash_equals(hash_hmac('sha256', $_GET['id'], $chave), $_GET['assinatura'])) {
    return
   // Assinatura é inválida;
}
```

A `$chave` provavelmente poderia ser substituída por `env('HMAC_KEY_DENUNCIA')`, *similar ao que o @Guilherme Nascimento mencionou*.

---

O "impacto de performance" não foi levado em consideração, a prioridade é exclusivamente resolver o problema da falta de autenticação (sem coletar informações adicionais sobre o usuário, e sem exigir login). Além disso, as hashes de proposito gerais são feitas para serem rápidas (principal Blake2 e Blake3).

Answer (score -3):

Alguns problemas desse tipo me incomodavam também. Minha alternativa foi criar tokens para os usuários, o que acabou me sendo muito útil e abriu novas funcionalidades no desenvolvimento. No meu caso criei mais uma coluna (token) para os usuários, gero uma string aleatória com sei lá, 60 dígitos, verifico se não está em uso e atribuo o valor ao usuário, assim você não o identificará o usuário sendo ID=32 e sim como token=Fdsfs#4g%fsflfqe1oi......foweu50ok.

Comment: Acho engraçado essa galera do down vote, pra vir participar da pergunta vem 2, pra negativar vem um punhado... Ajudar os colegas é difícil, criticar e desestimular quem tenta ajudar é fácil, né não. Nem para apontar erros ou mostrar onde a resposta está errada, transformando tudo em uma crítica construtiva servem, afinal, apontar o dedo (para baixo) é muito mais fácil, prático e cômodo do que pensar e escrever...